# How do I link into a specific volume and path in elfinder?

Tags: elfinder

Elfinder has 2 parts to a complete path.  The format is basically driveHash_pathHash.  To link to a file I need to use something like this. 
 http://example.com/elfinder#driveHash_pathHash

I've figured out how to convert my/file/path to pathHash from posts like this https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Getting-encoded-hash-from-the-path

How do I get the drive hash?  (referred to as volumeID if you follow that link.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driveHash ain't no hash at all.  It's just a string and a number.  So it can't be encoded and decoded like the pathHash.  The work-around for dealing with this - is to define it myself for elfinder in the config options.

```
'disks' => [

    'HD' => [
        'glideURL' => '/glide/HD',
        'driverId' => 'HD',
        'id' => '69',
    ],
...
```

Will make a url with #elf_HD69_Lw where:

1. elf_ just get's added by elfinder.
2. HD69_ is the concatination of the driverId and id that I set in the config.
3. Lw is the pathHash for /